# When using custom cursors, how can you set the I-bar cursor when hovering over text?

Tags: html, css

I am using a custom cursor set for my website (to override the ugly AA cursors that most modern Operating Systems employ). I have successfully set the custom pointer/cursor, but I am having some difficulty setting the I-bar cursor for when the user hovers over/selects text. Is there not an easy/general #text element to style all text on a web-page? I don't want to just change the cursor to an I-bar when I enter a div (as discussed in a similar stackoverflow post); I only want to change it when hovering over text. Thanks.

```
body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    cursor: url(../images/cursors/cursor.png), default;
}
a:link:active {
    cursor: url(../images/cursors/pointer_active.png), pointer ;
}
a:link {
    cursor: url(../images/cursors/pointer.png), pointer ;
}
input[type=text], #text {
    cursor: url(../images/cursors/text.png), text !important;
}
```

Comment: there isn't a text node selector in CSS to do this, I not sure but maybe you can do with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out while simplifying some of the extant stylesheets on my website:

```css
html { 
    cursor: url(cursors/crosshair.gif) 17 17, pointer;
}
body {
    cursor: initial;
}
```

Simple and concise.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following.

```
p, input {
  cursor: text;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. There are a few other elements I use that contain text (<time>, <dt>, <dd>, etc.). I guess I'll just have to set all of those to cursor: url(...), text; It would be nice if there was a universal selector for text, though..